# Gitlab with Container Registry behind reverse proxy

Tags: docker, nginx, gitlab, docker-registry, gitlab-omnibus

Does anyone have a running installation of nginx as a reverse proxy, unbound from gitlab where the internal gitlab container registry is running?

I've setup nginx and gitlab in docker containers and I can access gitlab with a suburl e.g. `my.domain.com/gitlab/`. However when I try to access the container registry for an example project I either end up getting `Bad Gateway` when using `docker login` or the container registry shows an error when accessing the site:

`Docker connection error We are having trouble connecting to the Container Registry. Please try refreshing the page. If this error persists, please review the troubleshooting documentation .`

I've been trying to figure out what settings I need for days and I don't understand what's going wrong, so if anyone can help I'd be really grateful.